# How do I remove an exit segue in XCode interface builder?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, interface-builder

I am really very new at ios programming.
I have this segue I attached to the exit of a view.
For the life of me I cannot sem to remove it. I can remove the method in the code but then I just get a warning. 
**How do I remove this attached presenting segue?**
[image: presenting segues]

Comment: `unwindToMain:` is not currently attached to any button, so I don't believe it is of any concern to you. You probably defined a method in your .m file called this with a segue as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your .h and .m files for the declaration and implementation of the segue. After you remove that try to clean build your app.

Comment: I didn't realize that the segues were coming directly from the .h and .m files. I thought that it was storing it in some XML file somewhere. Turns out it's a direct quote of the .h file.